# Open file with content resolver Android

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I have source code using the ContentResolver openFile method under API Level 29:

```
val file = contentResolver.openFile(uri, "r", null)
```

For my specific project, I need to use API Level 28.

When I sync Gradle after setting API Level 28, I am getting the following error:
"Unresolved reference: openFile"

By inspecting the symbols, I tried the following change:

```
val providerClient = contentResolver.acquireContentProviderClient(uri)
val file = providerClient?.openFile(uri, "r")
```

Then I am getting warning saying that provider client should be released.

What is the correct way to port my code to API Level 28 ?

```
private fun performInstallation(uri: Uri) {
        try {
            val packageInstaller = packageManager.packageInstaller
            val sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(
                PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
                    PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL
                )
            )
            val session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId)
            val uniqueName = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
            // 
            val file = contentResolver.openFile(uri, "r", null)
            val size = file?.statSize ?: throw IOException("Couldn't read file from provider!")
            file.close()
            val outputStream = session.openWrite(uniqueName, 0, size)
            val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
                ?: throw IOException("Couldn't read file from provider!")
            val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
            outputStream.use { output ->
                inputStream.use { input ->
                    do {
                        val read = input.read(buffer)
                        if (read > 0) {
                            output.write(buffer, 0, read)
                        }
                    } while (read != -1)
                }
                session.fsync(output)
            }
            val intent = Intent(ACTION_RESULT).also { it.putExtra(EXTRA_RESULT, "success") }
            val broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                applicationContext,
                0,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
            )
            session.commit(broadcast.intentSender)
            log("Successfully installed $uri!")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            val intent = Intent(ACTION_RESULT).also { it.putExtra(EXTRA_RESULT, e.message) }
            sendBroadcast(intent)
            loge("Error installing $uri", e)
        }
        mainHandler.post {
            stopForeground(true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I dont know what you want with File. But why not just opening an input stream with contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)? Or .openOutputStream()?

Comment: The File is simply used to get the size of the file to perform the file copy operation that follow.

Comment: You cannot simply use a File instance. And you do not need to know its size to make a copy.